# AudioKit: How to make Knob from AnalogSynthX-Example exponential instead of linear?

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

For volume controls in most cases it would be better if knob values would change exponential or logarithmical instead of linear. 
Where would be the best place within the Knob.swift of the AudioKit AnalogSynthX-Example class to scale the value to any kind of curve?

I think of

```
func setPercentagesWithTouchPoint(_ touchPoint: CGPoint) {
    // Knobs assume up or right is increasing, and down or left is decreasing
    let horizontalChange = Double(touchPoint.x - lastX) * knobSensitivity
    value += horizontalChange * (maximum - minimum)

    let verticalChange = Double(touchPoint.y - lastY) * knobSensitivity
    value -= verticalChange * (maximum - minimum)

    lastX = touchPoint.x
    lastY = touchPoint.y

    // TODO: map to exponential/log/any curve if -> knobType is .exp
    // ...

    delegate?.updateKnobValue(value, tag: self.tag)
}
```

but maybe someone did invent this wheel already? Thnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for asking. The cutoff knob in the Analog Synth X repo scales logarithmically. You can look at that for a simple example.

Plus, there are new knobs in the AudioKit ROM Player repo. These improved knob controls have adjustable taper curve scaling and range settings:

https://github.com/AudioKit/ROMPlayer